# Bootstrap table make displaying element in TR not expand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, html-table

I built a table with knockout and bootstrap to display anime entries. It's sortable by clicking the column name. When you do that however, the cell expands to accommodate the arrow after i display: inline from display: none. How do I change the CSS so the arrow is displayed on the cell but doesn't expand it?

Demo here: http://animelistmvc.apphb.com/AnimeList/Explore

**Html:**

```
<div class = "table-responsive">
             <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed ko-grid" cellspacing="0">
                  <thead>
                      <tr data-bind="foreach: columns" class="disableSelection">
                           <th>
                            <!-- $parent header is required inside a foreach loop -->
                           <a id="headerTitle" data-bind="text: headerText, click: $parent.sortTable"></a>
                           <span data-bind="attr: { class: $parent.currentColumn() == headerText ? 'isVisible' : 'isHidden' }">
                           <i data-bind="attr: { class: $parent.iconType }"></i>
                           </th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody data-bind="foreach:itemsOnCurrentPage">
                  <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns">
                            <!-- ko if: rowId-->
                                <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: rowAction + '/' + $parent[rowId]}"><span data-bind="text: typeof rowText == 'function' ? rowText($parent) : $parent[rowText] "></a></td>
                            <!--/ko-->
                            <!-- ko if: rowText && !rowId-->
                                <td><span data-bind="text: typeof rowText == 'function' ? rowText($parent) : $parent[rowText] "></span></td>
                            <!--/ko-->
                            <!-- ko if: rowImage-->
                                <td align="center"><img width="100" height="100" data-bind="attr:{src: $parent[rowImage]}" /></td>
                            <!--/ko-->
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
             </table>
           </div>
```

CSS:

```
.isVisible {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}

.isHidden {
    display: none;
}

#headerTitle {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.disableSelection {
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the arrow's CSS positioning is absolute, the document will not account for its space in the flow. Make the `th` that contains it `position:relative` and set the css for the isVisible arrow to

```
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  float: none;
```

Season to taste.